# Hide Navigation bar separator line on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios13

I have a view controller with a navigation bar with a large title. When I push the controller, only on iOS 13 is a line visible under the Navigation bar. How can I solve it?

I have already tried several solutions on Stack but they have not worked like:

```
let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
let navigationBarAppearence = UINavigationBarAppearance()
navigationBarAppearence.shadowColor = .clear
navigationBar?.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearence
```

With this snippet, even if I change the "clear color" with red color it is visible only in the first controller, in the pushed controller it is always gray.

How can I solve it?

Edit

I've solved with:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.shadowColor = nil
    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import UIKit

public protocol HideableHairlineHelper {
    func hideHairline()
    func showHairline()
}

extension HideableHairlineHelper where Self: UIViewController {

    public func hideHairline() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any)
    }

    public func showHairline() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not the solution I have adopted but I like it as a solution

Answer (score 4):

I've tried the above-suggested ones and failed to remove the navigation separator line. Eventually, I've figured it out that to use `TransparentBackground`

The trick is to initialize `UINavigationBarAppearance` with `TransparentBackground`. Then you could easily remove the horizontal line of the navigation bar.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.green // Required background color
```

Then add the appearance changes to the navigation item as the apple suggested.

```
self.navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
self.navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
self.navigationItem.compactAppearance = appearance
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my NavBar template I use on my controllers, there's no line.

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    let titleAttributes =
        [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18),
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
    ]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleAttributes
```

I obviously change the font size and colour around but that's the basic function I put for each controller to get it clear(translucent).